# Url Routing not working Rest Api codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am creating rest api using codeigniter and want to use function but after hit "http://localhost/codeigniter-rest-api-master/api/testing" showing me error 
"404 page not found".Where i am wrong ?

here is my "application/config/routes.php"

```
   $route['api'] = 'api/users/';
    //api/users
    $route['api/users'] = 'api/testing/testing/';
    $route['api/users/format/json'] = 'api/testing/testing/format/json';
    $route['api/users/format/xml'] = 'api/testing/testing/format/xml';
    $route['api/users/format/html'] = 'api/testing/testing/format/html';
    $route['api/users/format/csv'] = 'api/testing/users/format/csv';
    $route['api/users.json'] = 'api/testing/testing.json';
    $route['api/users.xml'] = 'api/testing/testing.xml';
    $route['api/users.html'] = 'api/testing/testing.html';
    $route['api/users.csv'] = 'api/testing/testing.csv';
```

here is my "application/controller/api/Users.php"

```
public function testing()
{
    echo "hello world";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `api/testing` route. Use something like this

```
$route['api/testing'] = 'api/users/testing/';
```

The route is `folder/controller_class/function`. I think you should read the [guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).
This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955395/9031693) would be helpful too.

Comment: not working ( in controller my controller there is folder name "api" , where users controller exist

Comment: How are you declaring routes?

Comment: with following code now i am getting correct result

$route["Users"]["GET"] = "api/index_get";

Comment: Good for you. I am currently trying to make rest api using CI too ;-)

Comment: i am using post method but not working , may i know why ?

$route["Users"]["POST"] = "api/index_get";

Comment: @amit is 'api' a controller file? without the code I can't help much. But check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710509/codeigniter-routing-and-rest-server)

Comment: api is my foldername in controller and in api folder there is Users controller